# Please explain to me the following.

Tags: bounded-variation

1)How does the graph of a funtion of bounded variation behave.
2)Why a bounded function is not always a function of bounded variation.Please explain graphically.
3)What purpose does bounded variation serve.I mean why they are defined.
Sorry if the question is already asked.
And thank you in advance.

Comment: For 2, think of a trigonometric function with a particular argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. On a interval, the length of the function's curve is finite.
2. Think of $\sin x^{-1}$ on $]0,1]$.
3. Let $f$ be of bounded variation. It has the following properties:

It is the difference of two bounded increasing functions.

The left and right limits exists at every point within $f$'s domain.

The discontinuity set of $f$ is countable, and $f$ is thus Riemann integrable.

$f'$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Sir this doesnt answer my question.As you.can see I have laid amphasis on the graph of function.

Comment: @RayeesAhmad The graph is smooth almost everywhere.

Comment: Will you explain a bit. Isnt the graph of $x\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$ smoth except on a countable set.Why is it not function of bounded variation.

Comment: @RayeesAhmad It is not smooth on any neighbourhood of $0$. Its derivative is unbounded there.

Comment: I said sir..Is it smoth almost everywhere???

Comment: @RayeesAhmad It depends on your definition of smooth of a graph. Its curve oscillates rapidly around $0$ and cannot be drawn to approximate the function itself.

Comment: Yes sir I have varified it from wolform but what is the significance of defining a function of bounded variation?

Comment: @RayeesAhmad It allows the function to have "good" properties as listed above, and guarentees differentiability at many points.